# creating a copy button using sql apex oracle

Tags: sql, oracle-apex

I wanted to create a copy button in a form but this button needs to work using an sql statement which will be like

`select name, address1, address2, zipcode, car_type, model from Users WHERE report_id=:report_id`

I will explain more into this with an example.

If on a report I have a list of users and when you click on one of the user, it will take you to a form. In this form you can exit and `save` it, where the `save button` is, they will be another button called `copy`, this button will use the `sql` above and will copy `SOME` information on the form based on the `report_id`(the current report being viewed/edit in the form.)

The `copy button` will redirect to a form page and will render the information it goes from that sql statement.

I want to use sql statement because in

`action when button clicked`

`with these values` it says that colons, commas show not be in those values for example address_1, car_type, and other datatype contents those and because of this, I do want to do it this way. I did try it but I kept getting a `404 error page` thats why I want to try the sql way.

How will I be able to do it this way please?

EDITTED TO ADD IMAGE FOR MY IDEA IN WHICH I THINK MIGHT SOLVE THIS PROBLEM
[image]

the image ABOVE shows my `COPY` button. as you can see I item and values is the `order_id`
[image]

The image above shows the `PROCESSES` in which the sql query is run and `condition` it is the copy `button`.

The way i think this will work is that when you click on the copy button, the sql query will run and use the current `order_id` on the `form` to get all the information in the sql and show it on the form field.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution. My query does work and the way I tried to do this was right. The issue was that in fields. I had the source type as `database column` which was wrong. I need to set it to `Static Assignment(Value equals source attribute)` and the sourced used to `only when current value in session state is null`

Answer (score 0):

It is not very clear.

1. Why do you need to use `report_id` ?
2. What is the purpose of storing it in your `Users` table?
3. Is the `Copy` button going to save changes to the database before redirecting to the second form?

If `3.` is `false`, **do not** use an SQL query as you will lose changes, you should get field values instead.
If `3.` is `true`, you will simply need to query your table to fill your second form.

What I understand is that **you simply need to get values from a form to fill another form**, so you can simply pass values in the URL. As you said, you can have some problem depending on your values (special characters). However, note that :

1. To pass a comma in the URL, enclose the item value with backslashes (e.g. `\45,9\`).
2. You cannot pass a parameter with a colon (`:`) in the URL. A solution would be to replace it with another character if it is possible.

**Another solution** is to use an **[apex collection](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E37097_01/doc/doc.42/e35127/apex_collection.htm#CACFAICJ)** to store your values.

Your `Save` button can for example run a process like the following (of course use your own item names) :

```
APEX_COLLECTION.CREATE_OR_TRUNCATE_COLLECTION('MY_COLLECTION');
APEX_COLLECTION.ADD_MEMBER(
        p_collection_name => 'MY_COLLECTION'
        p_c001            => :P1_NAME,
        p_c002            => :P1_ADDRESS1,
        p_c003            => :P1_ADDRESS2,
        p_c004            => :P1_CARTYPE,
        p_c005            => :P1_MODEL,
        p_n001            => :P1_ZIPCODE,
        p_d001            => SYSDATE
);
```

Then in your second form, you can base your item values on an **SQL query** to retrieve the right value. Example for `P2_NAME` :

```
SELECT c001 from APEX_COLLECTIONS WHERE COLLECTION_NAME = 'MY_COLLECTION';
```

Comment: thanks for your answer. In the department we have some old people that simply will use colon without the backslash, if it was only me making the report I wouldbt be asking this question but its a department use by many members of staff.

Comment: the solution I was thinking is to have a process with runs a query like `SELECT NAME, DOB INTO :NAME, :DOB FROM records WHERE rec_id=:rec_id` and the `CONDITION` for the process (`When Button Pressed`) the button will be the `copy` button. In the copy `button` in the `Set These Items` will be the `p2_record_id` and `With These Values` will be `&p2_record_id`. What I think this will do is run the `process` and use the `record_id` from the current form being viewed and use that to get the info into the redirect form page. Unfortunately, I can't get this to work.

Comment: In case you want to use comma or colon characters, you don't need to ask people to do the job of escaping/replacing characters! You can simply rework the values before passing them in the URL. About apex collections, it works like temporary tables, the fact is that you cannot use temporary tables in apex as it can result in session conflicts (apex session and database session). You can use a simple table instead, but I recommend you to use apex collections. Just read the documentation and try some examples, it is very simple. You can also Google for "apex collection example".

Comment: dont think this will work for me because It will request me having access to too many systems which I can't access... Just take a look at my last comment and see if that can be possible

Comment: I ahev edited my question and add teo screenshots to show what I mean. Hope that helps you answer this question. Thanks again

Comment: What are `:NAME` and `:DOB`, items? Where are they used ? And you set `P2_ORDER_ID` in session state when redirecting to page 3, but what is the purpose of this, I can't see where you are using it. Really I can't figure out what you are trying to do. Try to explain it clearly in **plain english**

Comment: :Name and :DOB are `p2_Name` and `p2_DOB`, sorry i missed the `p2` out in this example. 


Okay, Just imagine a `report(interactive)/form`.  you have a lot of report from 1-9000 and you wanted to create a new report but with some similar contents to report `8756`. Now you click on this report and it takes you to the `form` in the form you have all the information from report `8756` and you have some buttons `copy`, `save changes` buttons. You click on the `copy` button.

Comment: This button is meant to copy some information based on that example query above and then redirect back to the same form but WITHOUT the `id` of `8756`. 

For the `copy` button to work you need to use something maybe an sql. so it knows what to copy and where to copy it to.

Comment: in that screenshot, example what I am trying to do is set the `id` in the button and in the Proceses(you can find this when you click on edit page(number)) i have the sql in the sources and the copy is linked to the copy button.

what I think it should so is replace `:p2_rec_id` with the form `id` **AKA** `report ID`

Comment: When you say "_lot of report from 1-9000_", you mean records, right?

I assume you have created your region using `Form on a Table with Report`, so you have a page dedicated to the form, containing all your items, and the built-in `Cancel` and `Save changes` buttons, right?

And you want to copy the current form values into other items, and clear the form ("_redirect back to the same form but without the id_" as you said), right?

Comment: yes when you say `and clear the form` I hope you dont mean delete the current records because we are only copying to a new form and in the new form the person that copy it, will be able to add a few things and when the click on `save` it will save it as a new records and give it a new `id` (auto increment). 

so yes, what u said above is right

Comment: OK so your `copy` button will act like a `create` button but with pre-filled values. So indeed you can use an onsubmit process if you want (take a look at `Automatic Row Fetch`), but also URL, apex_collections, hidden items, etc. Of course by "_clear_" I meant remove value from the fields, not from the database.

Comment: I have create an example on apex.oracle.com/i/index.html and login in which the detail below. email:**test@gmail.com **Username:**VDSADHI **password:**test123 **workspace: UY_KENPACHI Application name is: copy_button P.S please make a copy of the application, give it your name and work on your copy. Thanks for your help

Comment: Your example works as expected. On `copy` button you redirect to the same page, you set the id (`P3_DEPTNO`) with the existing id and you fetch data from that same id... so of course nothing changes. Don't you expect a new id ?

Comment: ots not the same. I'm sure you know the meaning of the word `copy`. My button is meant to copy `SELECTED`(NOT ALL) values in the forms into a new form `WITHOUT` COpying the previous `id` in the form. The new form is gonna have its only unique `id` because it `id` datatype is `auto increment` my example looks like it works but it doesnt

Comment: So let the `DEPTNO` empty, why did you fill it ? You have to create a new record so only fill the other fields. I did the modification on your page (I simply changed items you set in the `copy` button, and disabled your `GetDetails` process), check if it is what you want... But for me this `copy` button is not really intuitive...

Comment: i know i told my boss that people can just copy and paste what they want but he said no... I will look at what u have done in a few hours

Comment: this is work i just looked at it because You are passing the values as a perimeter in the copy button `Set These Items` and `With These Values` **BUT** this is what I am trying to avoid... IF YOU CLICK ON `With These Values` you will see it says most not contain `colons`, etc, **REMEMBER** i said before that some of my fields contains `COLONS` this was why I didn't want to do it this way that you just did because I get a 404 error page because of the colons. **P.S. I told you to make a copy of the application and not to work on the orignal**

Comment: 1. We are not at your service, mind your language. 
2. Write better English and check your text before posting. 
3. I gave you different solutions in my answer, you should have tried them. 
4. Avoid creating 4 different topics about a single problem. 
5. Your "solution" is not the source of your problem. 
6. Read the documentation. 
7. A word to the wise!

Comment: I know u aint in my service 2) I didnt use any bad language 3) English is my fourth langauage 4) I clearly said "make a copy of the application" which you CHOOSE to ignore 5) I did try your solution you provided by none of them worked 6) Thanks for your help with the topics, I realy do appreciate it 7) Have a great day